# How to naming list elements using only lapply in R

Tags: r, apply, lapply

This is my list:

```
l <- vector("list", 4)
l[[1]][1] <- list(c(1,2,3))
l[[1]][2] <- list(c(1,2,3))

l[[2]][1] <- list(c(1,2,3))
l[[2]][2] <- list(c(1,2,3))

l[[3]][1] <- list(c(1,2,3))
l[[3]][2] <- list(c(1,2,3))

l[[4]][1] <- list(c(1,2,3))
l[[4]][2] <- list(c(1,2,3))
```

I have this names vectors: `mynames <- c("number one","number two")`

How can I name the list elements using the `lapply` function with the  `mynames` vector?

I tried this, but didn't work:

```
lapply(l,  names(x) <- mynames)
```

Any help?

Comment: You can use the functional form of a "special" function, something like `lapply(l, \`names<-\`, mynames)` (which is equivalent to `lapply(l, function(a) \`names<-\`(a, mynames))` which is equivalent to `lapply(l, function(a) { names(a) <- mynames; a; })`).

Comment: @r2evans many thanks. This is amazing. I am a begginer in lapply. How can I understand more this sintax such as `names<-`? I had no idea that I could use this in lapply. Any suggestion to read?

Comment: When you do something like `names(x) <- c('a','b','c')`, there is a function called `names` which only returns the names of the object `x`, and there is a function called `names<-` (no space) that is called when `names(x)` is on the left side of an assignment operator (`<-` or `=`). Most functions do not have this assignment equivalent; more the point, it does not make sense for most functions to do something on the assignment-side (left-hand side). There are some other minor differences, not really notable here. BTW: I think @Parfait's suggestion to use `setNames` is simpler and just as good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `lappyl()` has to be a function. One can use `setNames()`:

```
named_list <- lapply(l, setNames, nm=mynames)
named_list[1:2]
[[1]]
[[1]]$`number one`
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]]$`number two`
[1] 1 2 3


[[2]]
[[2]]$`number one`
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]$`number two`
[1] 1 2 3
```

An alternative version based on the replacement function `` `names<-` `` is:

```
named_list2 <- lapply(l, function(x, names) { names(x) <- names; x },
                      names=mynames)
identical(named_list, named_list2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I assumed that Laura would prefer to not discard the data when naming it. Perhaps return `a` from the inner function?

Comment: Nice preservation of scope by adding the `names=` argument.

Comment: @r2evans thanks for the comment. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Florian many thanks. 
@r2evans many thanks. As I said, I am a begginer in lapply. How can I understand more this sintax such as `names<-`? I had no idea that I could use this in lapply. Any suggestion to read? This sintax ``names<-`` has any name?

Comment: Consider even the left hand function, `setNames`: `lapply(l, function(x) setNames(x, mynames))`

Comment: @Parfait adorable answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Parfait using `setNames()` is a great idea. See the updated answer.